# Is $x \approx x$?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

If I write $x \approx y$, does this mean (a) $x$ is sufficiently close to $y$ for some practical purpose, or (b) $x$ is sufficiently close to $y$ for some practical purpose, but is not equal to $y$?

If (a) is true, then it appears $x \approx x$.

This question appears to have more importance when considering something like the small angle approximations. Is the statement $\sin(x) \approx x $ true when $0 \leq x \leq 1$, or true when $0<\sin(x) \leq 1$?

Comment: For your final question, saying $0<\sin x≤ 1$ isn't enough to ensure that the approximation holds (however you interpret it).  $\sin (2\pi+\epsilon)$ is in that range, for instance (if $\epsilon>0$ is small enough).

Comment: It would be useless to require $x \ne y$.  For one thing, that would be impossible to verify in most situations where you need to use an approximation.

Comment: @PeterForeman: $\ll 1$ is not necessarily intended. The distance to the Moon is $\approx 384 400$ km.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: yep, it would even be an embarrassing convention. F.i. $x>10\implies C(x)\approx 1$ (Fresnel Cosine) would be wrong infinitely many times.

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is a very logical explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind that "$\approx$" isn't actually a formal notion at the outset, any reasonable approach to it (e.g. via nonstandard analysis, where "$\approx$" is interpreted as "is in the halo of") will say that it **does** extend equality: everything is approximately equal to itself.

It's worth noting that the way approximation is cropping up here is in questions of **asymptotics**: when we say "$x\approx \sin(x)$ near $0$," we don't really care about how close $\sin(0.1)$ is to $0.1$, what we're really interested in is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(x)\over x}$. There **is** a formal framework for discussing this sort of analysis, namely [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and its relatives, and in this framework everything is indeed close to itself.

Comment: The asymptotic analysis would rather say $\sin x\sim x$, with the meaning that the limit of the ratio is $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Did I claim otherwise?

Comment: Sorry but you are creating confusion by mixing two notations and two concepts.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't understand. What are the two notations/concepts I'm mixing?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm happy to edit my answer but I'm not sure what you're objecting to.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Assuming you're the downvoter, can you please clarify what you disagree with in my answer?

Comment: I think the point is that the two distinct symbols $\sim$ and $\approx$ are related: the mathematical statement is $\sin(x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$, the practical application is that $\sin(0.01) \approx 0.01$.

Answer (score 0):

(a) holds.

Your final question is unrelated/illogical: (a) deals with $x\approx x$ or $\sin x\approx\sin x$, but not $\sin x\approx x$.